# Can't integrate INNER JOIN in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm using the query below to select the latest message from each unique conversation. Everything works perfectly except when I try to integrate an `INNER JOIN` to try to link the user's `user_id` with their `username` in the `users` table.

I've tried pretty much every combination to integrate the `INNER JOIN` so I decided to separate it from the working query until I get help.

**I made a Fiddle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9bbc/1   I just want user_id on the right to print the user's username

```
SELECT message_id, 
       msg, 
       user_id 
FROM   messages 
   JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                Max(dat) m 
         FROM   ((SELECT message_id, 
                         recipient_id user_id, 
                         dat 
                  FROM   messages 
                  WHERE  owner_id = 1) 
                 UNION 
                 (SELECT message_id, 
                         owner_id user_id, 
                         dat 
                  FROM   messages 
                  WHERE  recipient_id = 1)) t1 
         GROUP  BY user_id) t2 
     ON ( ( owner_id = 1 
            AND recipient_id = user_id ) 
           OR ( owner_id = user_id 
                AND recipient_id = 1 ) ) 
        AND ( dat = m ) 
 ORDER  BY dat DESC
```

.

```
users.username INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.user_id;
```

Comment: whats users.username here -schemaname.tablename or tablename.column name?

Comment: tablename.column

Comment: you should use join with tables , and you are doing wrong here. It should be messages inner join users on messages.user_id = users.User_Id

Comment: Appreciate the help @ Aswani. Check out my edit.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `messages.message_id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column, this will probably be the fastest way to receive the desired result:

```
select m.message_id, m.msg, u.username,
  case sub.other_user_id
    when m.owner_id     then 'received from'
    when m.recipient_id then 'sent to'
  end as direction
from (
  select other_user_id, max(message_id) as message_id
  from (
    select recipient_id as other_user_id, max(message_id) as message_id
    from messages
    where owner_id = @uid
    group by recipient_id

    union all

    select owner_id as other_user_id, max(message_id) as message_id
    from messages
    where recipient_id = @uid
    group by owner_id
  ) sub
  group by other_user_id
) sub
join messages m on m.message_id = sub.message_id
join users u    on u.user_id    = sub.other_user_id
order by sub.message_id desc
```

I've also added the column `direction`. This way you will know if the message has been sent or received. The result would be like:

```
| message_id |                                                              msg | username |     direction |
|------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|---------------|
|          9 | You should also see this                                         |    User3 |       sent to |
|          8 | you should Now see this instead even with the owner_id flipped.. |    User2 | received from |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9bbc/34

Note that you can still add any column from the `users` and `messages` tables in the SELECT clause.

To get this query work fast you will need indexes on `messages(owner_id, recipient_id)` and `messages(recipient_id, owner_id)`.

Comment: Very elegant solution

Comment: 2 sends to 3 (doesn't work):  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0858dd/1)

Comment: @Zorkolot If User2 sends a message to User3, they (usually) don't want User1 to see it :-) Note that `@uid` has to be replaced by the `user_id` of the user which is sending the request. In this case it's User1 with `user_id = 1`. And we only want to see messages sent to or received from this user.

Comment: Maybe this is interpretation... OP starts off saying "select the latest message from each unique conversation".  Your fiddle however, selects the latest message from one conversation.  It might be what Julian wants though... anyway I was confused by the output.

Comment: @Zorkolot Well - you are right, if the quote has to be taken strictly. But OP also posted a "working" query using `owner_id = 1` and `recipient_id = 1`. So it should be a comment to OP, to fix the inconsistency in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct... finally.  The not exists filters out responses after the start.. the inner query grabs the most recent conversation. This should match the expected output.

```
SELECT dT.maxid AS message_id
      ,(SELECT msg FROM messages M WHERE M.message_id = dT.maxid) AS message_id
      ,(SELECT username FROM users U WHERE U.user_id = dT.owner_id) AS user_id      
  FROM (  
         SELECT MAX(message_id) as maxid
               ,owner_id
               ,recipient_id
           FROM messages M
         GROUP BY owner_id, recipient_id
       ) AS dT
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                   FROM messages M2
                  WHERE M2.recipient_id = dT.owner_id
                    AND M2.owner_id = dT.recipient_id
                    AND M2.message_id > dT.maxid)
ORDER BY dT.maxid
```

Produces output:

```
message_id  message_id                                             user_id
8           you should Now see this instead even with the          User2
            owner_id flipped.. The users_id in the query is 1 
            and it gets the conversation with user_id 2 
9           You should also see this                               User1
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c50309/1/0)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e120/1) ... What I want is for `user_id` on the right to print the users `username`

Comment: @Julian this might be it  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ed6e8/3/0)

Comment: I just realized that your solution prints out the right response, but not what I'm looking for.  I updated the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9bbc/1) with what I'm looking for... I need it to display the most resent message in a conversation regardless of the `owner_id` or `recipient_id` The user_id in the query is `1` so it would get the most recent message in each of the conversation's it's in. Thanks again

Comment: @Julian Well... I might not be able to transform what I did, but you could just subquery your id for the name.  Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9bbc/7/0)

Comment: `GROUP BY owner_id, recipient_id` will not group sent and received messages together.

Answer (score 0):

When you have joined any tables or subqueries, you really really really need to include table name or table aliases with all column references. I changed the maximum dat to maxdat below so I could use m for messages.

```
SELECT
      m.message_id
    , m.msg
    , m.user_id
FROM messages m
JOIN (
      SELECT
            user_id
          , MAX(dat) maxdat
      FROM (
            (SELECT
                  message_id
                , recipient_id user_id
                , dat
            FROM messages
            WHERE owner_id = 1)
            UNION
            (SELECT
                  message_id
                , owner_id user_id
                , dat
            FROM messages
            WHERE recipient_id = 1)
      ) t1
      GROUP BY
            user_id
) t2 ON (
         (m.owner_id = 1 AND m.recipient_id = t2.user_id)
      OR (m.owner_id = t2.user_id AND m.recipient_id = 1)
        )
      AND (m.dat = t2.maxdat)
ORDER BY
      m.dat DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent messages where the send or recipient is "1" and associated user names.

That suggests:

```
select m.*, ur.username as recipient_name, us.username as sender_name
from messages m join
     users ur
     on m.recipient_id = ur.user_id join
     users us
     on m.sender_id = us.user_id
where m.date = (select max(m2.dat)
                from messages m2
                where 1 in (m2.recipient_id, m2.sender_id)
               ) and
      1 in (m.recipient_id, m.sender_id);
```

EDIT:

Based on your SQL Fiddle the above understanding is not correct.  You want to consider pairs of recipients, so I think you want:

```
select m.*, ur.username as recipient_name, us.username as sender_name
from messages m left join
     users ur
     on m.recipient_id = ur.user_id left join
     users us
     on m.owner_id = us.user_id
where m.dat = (select max(m2.dat)
               from messages m2
               where (m2.recipient_id, m2.owner_id) = (m.recipient_id, m.owner_id) or
                     (m2.recipient_id, m2.owner_id) = (m.owner_id, m.recipient_id)
              ) and
      1 in (m.recipient_id, m.owner_id);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14498d/13) is the SQL Fiddle.

If the ordering of the pair is import (so `(1, 2)` is different from `(2, 1)` remove the second condition in the innermost `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sadly I got the error `Unknown column 'ur.name' in 'field list'` I added some sample data to the edit.

Comment: tried your new edit but still no avail... I made a fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14498d/2) I just want the users username instead of their user_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your final result with users table and get the value of users.username based on user_id. Try this:

```
SELECT messages.message_id, 
   messages.msg,
   users.user_id,
   users.username   
FROM   users, messages 
  JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
            Max(dat) m 
     FROM   ((SELECT message_id,
                     users.username,
                     recipient_id user_id, 
                     dat 
              FROM   messages
              INNER JOIN users ON messages.recipient_id = users.user_id
              WHERE  owner_id = 1) 
             UNION 
             (SELECT message_id,
                     users.username,
                     owner_id user_id, 
                     dat 
              FROM   messages
               INNER JOIN users ON messages.owner_id = users.user_id
              WHERE  recipient_id = 1)) t1 
     GROUP  BY user_id) t2 
 ON ( ( owner_id = 1 
        AND recipient_id = user_id ) 
       OR ( owner_id = user_id 
            AND recipient_id = 1 ) ) 
    AND ( dat = m ) 
WHERE users.user_id = messages.user_id
ORDER  BY dat DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I got this error ` Unknown column 'messages.user_id' in 'where clause'`